# leaflet-sidebar (display data in the sidebar when a marker is clicked)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm new to leaflet and I'm struggling on how can I output the data of a marker into the sidebar when the marker is clicked.

this is the javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   getUsers();
});

//map settings

var map = L.map('map').setView([10.3157, 123.8854], 12);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamhvbmFsYmVydG1lZGlkYSIsImEiOiJjaXdhdzFlaXAwMHF2MnRrMmF6czZ6dGltIn0.kzH7HqjnyXsVBxbMdzqlXg', {
         attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
         maxZoom: 18,
         minZoom: 12,
         zoomControl: true
    }).addTo(map);
    map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');

    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
            closeButton: true,
            position: 'left'
        });
        map.addControl(sidebar);

        map.on('click', function () {
            sidebar.hide();
        })




// Get Data
function getUsers() {
    $.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('json/convert');?>", function (data) { //get json data from json.php

        var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup(); //create a cluster group

         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);

            var rid = data[i].report_id; //information in the table reports
            var rclass = data[i].report_classification;
            var rstatus = data[i].report_status;
            var pdate = data[i].date_posted;
            var barangay = data[i].barangay;
            var river = data[i].river;
            var bridge = data[i].bridge;
            var cdetails = data[i].complaint_details;

            var redMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({  //leaflet markers
                icon: 'exclamation-circle',
                markerColor: 'red',
                prefix: 'fa'
              });
            var greenMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                icon: 'check-circle',
                markerColor: 'green',
                prefix: 'fa'
              });
             var orangeMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                icon: 'spinner',
                markerColor: 'orange',
                prefix: 'fa',
                spin: true
              });

            var myIcon; //condition for markers
                switch(rstatus) 
                {
                  case "2":
                    myIcon = redMarker;
                  break;
                  case "3":
                    myIcon = orangeMarker;
                  break;
                  case "4":
                    myIcon = greenMarker;
                  break;
                default:
                    myIcon = redMarker;
                }


            var marker = L.marker([data[i].lat, data[i].lng], { icon: myIcon });
            marker.bindPopup("<h4><center >"+barangay+ " - " + bridge + "</h4><br>" + pdate + " : " +cdetails);
            //marker.on('mouseover', marker.openPopup.bind(marker));
            //marker.on('mouseout', marker.closePopup.bind(marker));

            marker.on("click", function (e) {
            //var clickedMarker = event.layer;
            var visible = sidebar.isVisible();
            sidebar.setContent(""+barangay);


            if (!visible){
              sidebar.toggle();

            }

            });

            if(rstatus==0 || rclass==0 || rclass==1){

            map.removeLayer(marker);

            }
            else{

            markerClusters.addLayer(marker);
            map.addLayer( markerClusters );

            }

         }


    })
}
</script>
```

The only output that i can see in the sidebar is the last data that is inputted into the database, but when i clicked on the other markers the data in the sidebar does not change. How can I improved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional attributes to each marker to store reference to data or data itself:

```
var marker = L.marker([36,5], {myCustomId: "abc123"});
```

Use these additional attributes to obtain detail for specific marker on desired event:

```
marker.on("click", function (e) {
        sidebar.setContent(""+this.options.myCustomId);
```

S2